# Spark Scala Dataframe case when like function

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am using spark scala with DataFrame API, trying to convert the below sql logic

```
   CASE 
     WHEN col_1 like '%XYZ' OR col_1 like '%ZYX' THEN 
       CASE WHEN col_2 like '%TTT' THEN 'ABC' ELSE 'BBA' END
     WHEN col_1 not like '%XYZ' OR col_1 not like '%ZYX' 
       CASE WHEN col_2 like '%YYY' THEN BBC' END
   END as new_col
```

How to construct CASE WHEN with multiple like and not like conditions with spark scala dataframe api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expr function and pass the whole case statement in it as below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=Seq(
      ("A","01/01/2022",1), ("AXYZ","02/01/2022",1), ("AZYX","03/01/2022",1),("AXYZ","04/01/2022",0), ("AZYX","05/01/2022",0),("AB","06/01/2022",1), ("A","07/01/2022",0) ).toDF("Category", "date", "Indictor")


df.select(col("*"),expr("""CASE WHEN Category like '%XYZ' OR Category like '%ZYX' THEN 
                                   CASE WHEN Indictor = 1 THEN 'ABC' ELSE 'BBA' END
                                WHEN Category not like '%XYZ' OR Category not like '%ZYX' then
                                    CASE WHEN Indictor = 1 THEN 'BBC' ELSE 'BBD' END
                                END""").alias("new_col")).show()
```

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|Category|      date|Indictor|new_col|
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|       A|01/01/2022|       1|    BBC|
|    AXYZ|02/01/2022|       1|    ABC|
|    AZYX|03/01/2022|       1|    ABC|
|    AXYZ|04/01/2022|       0|    BBA|
|    AZYX|05/01/2022|       0|    BBA|
|      AB|06/01/2022|       1|    BBC|
|       A|07/01/2022|       0|    BBD|
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using when( $"col".like( "%XYZ" ) || $"col".like( "%ZYX" ) , "BBA" ) , and it worked